# Returning a reference to a forward-declared type (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, forward-declaration

I have a class method that returns a reference to something. When I use this method, if I only have a forward declaration of that something, I can only compile if I assign the output of the method. I really don't understand why...

Here's a simplified example:

**ClassA.h:**

```
//Forward declare
class ClassB;

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(void);
    ~ClassA(void);

    ClassB& Func();
};
```

**ClassA.cpp:**

```
#include "ClassA.h"

#include "ClassB.h"

ClassA::ClassA(void)
{}

ClassA::~ClassA(void)
{}

static ClassB c;

ClassB& ClassA::Func()
{
    return c;
}
```

**ClassB.h:**

```
#pragma once
class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB(void) {};
    ~ClassB(void) {};
};
```

Now, if I call `ClassA::Func` without assigning the return value (while only having a forward declaration of `ClassB`), it will not compile:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "ClassA.h"

int main(void)
{
    ClassA a;

    a.Func(); //error C2027: use of undefined type 'ClassB'

    return 0;
}
```

If I use this line instead, it works: `ClassB& b = a.Func();`

What's happening here? Why would the compiler need to know the size of `ClassB` or what its methods are when the return value is not assigned anywhere?

I'm compiling this with VisualStudio 2010 SP1.

Comment: Looks like a  compiler bug, as you say there is no reason the compiler needs to know anything about `ClassB` to be able to discard the reference if you don't bind it to anything.

Comment: Can reproduce in VS2012 too.

Comment: Is it in both debug and release ?

Comment: @quantdev in 2012, yes.

Comment: This [gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/629420-compiler-discrepancy-use-of-undefined-type/) thread discusses this issue. They concluded the problem is that VC++ can't cast an undefined type to `void` (which is what you're supposed to do with unused return values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a "limitation" of the compiler, [the MSDN page for C2027 says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c2dk0ah.aspx) :

> It is possible to declare a pointer to a declared but undefined type. **But Visual C++ does not allow a reference to an undefined type.**
>
> The following sample generates C2027.

And gives this example :

```
class A;
A& CreateA();

class B;
B* CreateB();

int main() {
   CreateA();   // C2027
   CreateB();   // OK
}
```

So both of your examples are supposed to generate a C2027, I'm not sure why the second does not (that is, without more documentation, it is a bug)

Comment: Except it obviously does, since the error goes away if the return value is assigned. ??

Comment: @dlf I dont get why the second does not generate an error, but the OP code is similar to the MSDN example giving an error.

Comment: I agree. Either their documentation is wrong (incomplete), or the fact that the other case does work is a "bug" in that it follows the standard where the documentation says it shouldn't.

Comment: It also compiles in a case like this:
`A&   Func1();`
`void Func2(A&);`
`Func2(Func1());`

I'm guessing this reacts the same as an assignation.

I always thought using references with a forward declaration was just as acceptable as using a pointer. Their documentation does seem incomplete on this.

Also, what happens with other compilers?

Comment: @SamuelDelisle gcc and clang are standard compliant with this : i.e. it works in both cases. Hope this helps.